# is the answer in terms of variables or numbers?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Question:

"A spherical balloon is inflated with gas at the rate of 800 cubic centimeters per minute. How fast is the radius of the balloon increasing at the instant the radius is (a) 30 centimeters and (b) 60 centimeters?" (Larson Calculus P 153).

In this problem and in general how would you know if the expected answer is in terns of variables or numbers??

Comment: It looks like the kind of problem that ultimately will have a numerical answer. If the problem asked for the rate at which the radius is increasing when the radius is $r$, then one would expect the answer to be in terms of $r$. For this problem, we might want to take that approach, since we want the answer for two different values of $r$.

Comment: @AndreNicolas, what if there is air escaping??

Comment: @Amad27 After weeks of ignoring the point on the xkcd math forums until the point where your conversation gets locked, you come here and try to raise the same point?  Good luck.  (to anyone else who wants to see the original thread on it, it's here: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=109699 ).

Comment: The air escaping is not a big issue, we have not been told any is escaping. There is a more serious problem which will make the answer we get using "related rates" physically wrong. As we pump air into the balloon, the **pressure** inside the balloon will change. So at the beginning, when we pump in $800$ cc the volume increases by about $800$. But after a while, pumping in $800$ cc does not give us a volume increase of $800$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, then what do you suggest we do?

Comment: The answer would be dependent on physical properties of the balloon. For a realistic model, we need to build in information about the response of the material to pressure.

Comment: @AndréNicolas but this is just a textbook problem. Do you make assumptions based on the fact that the problem has a solution?

Comment: In textbook problems there are (often implicit) conventions about the level of sophistication of the mathematical model that is to be used. I prefer explicitness. So I would prefer that the question told us how fast the volume is increasing, not how fast air is being pumped in.

Comment: @AndréNicolas exactly my point... that would be much better and easier to understand. So a problem will have a variables-solution if it has variables STATED, and a numerical solution if only numbers are given?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, did you have time to read the comment?

Comment: Yes, I did. There is nothing useful I can add. About the sentence "So a problem $\dots", I am uncomfortable with generalities about problem-solving. A problem that appears to be purely numerical may be best approached in a general way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas it is fairly interesting to see what you are talking about. Without generalities, how will you be able to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$V=\frac {4 \pi r^3}3$

$\frac {dV}{dt}=800=4 \pi r^2\frac {dr}{dt}$

Well its simple just write down the equations that are given and determine what you need to find. If all numerical values are present then you can find a numerical answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, what I do is write down all of the equations I need (i.e., what is the equation for volume), and if I have all of the values that go into the equation, I give the answer as a number because I can calculate it. If I don't, I do as much as I can and leave the rest in terms of (unknown) variables. Your problem seems to be of the numerical type.

Answer (score 0):

Volume, $V(t)$, as function of time $t$ has a constant speed (volume inflation speed is constant). So:
$$V'(t)=800$$
for all $t$, is assumed.
Volume is also viewed here as a function of radius: $ V(t)=\tilde{V}(r(t))$, with $\tilde{V}(x) =4/3\pi x^3$, and radius is denoted by $r(t)$, also a function of time $t$. What about the speed of radius increase, $r'(t)$?
From:
$$ V(t)=\tilde{V}(r(t))=4/3\pi r(t)^3$$
we get 
$$ V'(t)= 800= 4\pi r(t)^2r'(t),$$
for all $t$.

Let $t_1$ be the time when $r(t_1)=30$. Then, taking $t=t_1$ in above equation we get:
$$ 800 = 4\pi 30^2r'(t_1),$$
and solve for $r'(t_1)$. Same for the other case. These are answers for specific instants. In general, we do have:
$$ r'(t) = \frac{800}{4\pi r(t)^2}$$
for all $t$.